# Anova shows a main effect but not the t-test

Tags: r, mixed-model, anova, interaction, main-effects

I run an ANOVA which indicates that a variable is significant, but running a t-test on the same variable shows no significance. Is this a consistent result ?

Here are more details of what I did:

My hypothesis is that for individuals completing the experiment in room 1, anxiety will be different between time 1 and 2. But for individuals in room 2 anxiety won't be different

`anova_test(x, dv = anxiety, wid=ID, between = room, within = time)`

```
            Effect DFn DFd     F     p p<.05   ges
1          room   1  34 0.801 0.377       0.018
2          time   1  34 5.898 0.021     * 0.035
3     room:time   1  34 0.950 0.337       0.006
```

Here is the t-test on 'time' variable:
`t.test(x[x$time=='1','anxiety'],x[x$time=='2',anxiety'])`

t-test : p-value = 0.1207

p-value from t-test is 0.1207 while in the ANOVA it shows 0.021.

How is it possible to make sense of these results ?

Comment: I assume that above "But for individuals anxiety won't be different" you might mean "But for individuals IN ROOM 2 anxiety won't be different". I assume this is referring to the function "anova_test" in package "rstatix"?

Comment: Yes exactly, I just edited the post

Answer (score 2):

I do not have your data but you are testing two different things. In the ANOVA model you are testing for the effect of room, time and their interaction in anxiety, in an analysis that uses the individual ID as information (so measurements within individual are correlated)  while in the t-test, you are completely ignoring the effect of the room in anxiety and you are assuming all observations to be independent. Therefore, there's no reason why the results should be the same - you are testing fundamentally different things.

Comment: What If I specify the t-test as paired, what is happening exactly ? I know by doing so, the observations are not independent anymore, but still getting a non-significant value p = 0.1

Comment: Note one apporach still assumes that the effect in anxiety is just due to time, the other incorporates the effect of the room and a possible interaction of room with time. Therefore, no reason why the results should be the same. If the effect of X1 on Y also depends on X2 and X2 is not accounted for in the analysis, you might conclude wrongly about the effect of X1 on Y.